# String in Array of numbers gives error

Tags: vba, excel

```
Sub highlight()
   Dim w As Workbook
   Dim sh As Worksheet
   Dim x As Integer
   Dim rn As Range
   Dim k As Long
   Dim number As Variant

   number = Array(9811, 7849)


   Set w = ThisWorkbook


   Set sh = w.Worksheets("Sheet1")
   sh.Select
   Cells.Find("hello").Select
   ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
   Set rn = sh.UsedRange
   k = rn.Rows.Count + rn.Row - 1
   For x = 1 To k
      For j = 0 To UBound(number)
         If ActiveCell.Value <> number(j) Then
            Selection.Interior.Color = vbYellow
         Else
            Selection.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
            Exit For
         End If

      Next j
      ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select 'moves activecell down one row.
   Next x

End Sub
```

The above code works completely fine.
Now, when I send the same numbers (9811,7849) from my GUI to the below vba code,they are stored as phm="9811,7849". So Array("9811,7849") gives me incorrect result.Any ideas how to make it work correctly?\

```
sub highlight(phm as variant)
Dim w As Workbook
Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim x As Integer
Dim rn As Range
Dim k As Long
Dim number As Variant


number = Array(phm)
```

Comment: That's unreadable. fix your indentation, explain your code, explain what result is incorrect.

Comment: indentation is correct..i have posted two codes. The first one is what i have tried and second one is what i want

Comment: Incorrect implies all the cells are getting highlighted instead of mismatched ones.I konw the error is because of this:number=Array("9811,7849"). Im unable to fix it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Array("9811,7849")` is an array with one `String` element: `"9811,7849"`

And `Array(9811,7849)` is an array with two elements: `9811` and `7849`

You should take a look at the `Split()` function

```
number=Split(phm,",")
```

And if you need `number` as Integer, apply also `CInt()`:

```
Dim number() As Integer
phm=Split("9811,7849",",")
ReDim number(LBound(phm) To UBound(phm)) As Integer
For i=LBound(phm) To UBound(phm)
  number(i)=CInt(phm(i))
Next i
```

## Edit

You requested in the comments to add this snippet to your subroutine:

```
Sub highlight(ByVal phm As String)
   Dim w As Workbook
   Dim sh As Worksheet
   Dim x As Integer
   Dim rn As Range
   Dim k As Long
   Dim number() As String


   number = Split(phm, ",")


   Set w = ThisWorkbook


   Set sh = w.Worksheets("Sheet1")
   sh.Select
   Cells.Find("hello").Select
   ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
   Set rn = sh.UsedRange
   k = rn.Rows.Count + rn.Row - 1
   For x = 1 To k
      For j = 0 To UBound(number)
         If ActiveCell.Value <> number(j) Then
            Selection.Interior.Color = vbYellow
         Else
            Selection.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
            Exit For
         End If

      Next j
      ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select 'moves activecell down one row.
   Next x

End Sub
```

Comment: If ActiveCell.Value= number(j) Or ActiveCell.Value=vbNullString Then
            Selection.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
         Else
            Selection.Interior.Color = vbRed,......
           All the the cells except the blank cells are highlighted as red.